# Не получается достучаться до сервиса в контейнере docker

Tags: asp.net, nginx, docker

Не понимаю, почему я не могу достучаться до своего сервиса через localhost с помощью промежуточного прокси-сервера в виде nginx (который также разворачивается в контейнере).
Собственно, вот код docker-compose:

```
version: '3.4' 
 
services: 
  mirror: 
    image: mirror 
    build: 
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Mirror/Dockerfile 
    ports: 
      - 5000:80 
  proxy: 
    image: nginx:latest 
    volumes: 
      - ./Mirror/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d 
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000
```

Файл настройки сервера nginx.info:

```
worker_processes 4; 
 
events { worker_connections 1024; } 
 
http { 
    sendfile on; 
 
    upstream app_servers { 
        server mirror:80; 
    } 
 
    server { 
    listen 3000; 
    location / { 
        proxy_pass         http://app_servers; 
        proxy_http_version 1.1; 
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive; 
        proxy_set_header   Host $host; 
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade; 
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
      } 
    } 
}
```

Я предполагал, что открываю порт 3000 во внешнюю сеть, который будет пробрасывать на порт 3000 в nginx (он его должен слушать в docker). Далее прокси-сервер передаст данные на порт 80 моему приложению ASP.NET. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: А где вы 5000 порт слушаете? Ваше приложение - это сервис mirror или оно на хост-машине?

Comment: а вы уверены что названия nginx.info у вас правильное и путь для монтирования файла тоже: `- ./Mirror/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d` (с такой записью, контейнер с nginx скорее всего даже стартовать не будет)? скорее всего должно быть что-то такое: `- ./Mirror/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro`

Comment: и вы логи проверяли, что там написано?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, благодарю, Вы мне помогли. Файл nginx.info переименовал в nginx.conf, изменил путь, после чего это сработало для меня.